# OOP, Constructor not working

Tags: c++

I am trying to call constructor  but it is not working. Code is something like this:

## // Event.h

```
class Event
{
  private:
    int Time;
    int Date;
  public:
    Event();
    Event(int t, int d)
}
```

## // Event.cpp

```
Event::Event(){}

Event::Event(int time, int date){
Time=time;
Date=date;
}
```

---

//Now in another .cpp file I am trying to call constructor something like this:

```
Event eve;
eve(inputTime,inputDate); // inputTime and inputDate are inputs 4m user.
//Error is:  no match for call to â(Event) (Time&, Date&)â
```

Any suggestions..............

Comment: It seems the arguments you pass have diffeent types than what the constructor expects.

Comment: @DietmarKuhl Gotcha...Thats the problem . Thanks a lot.

Comment: @HardCode that is only part of the problem. See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This

```
eve(inputTime,inputDate);
```

requires that your `Event` class have an `operator()(something, somethingElse)`, which it doesn't have. `something` and `somethingElse` would correspond to the types of `inputTime` and `inputDate` respectively, which are not specified in your question.

Presumably you want to construct an `Event` using the two argument constructor, which you can do like this:

```
Event eve(inputTime,inputDate);
```

Since the error also mentions types `Time` and `Date`, you probably need to add a constructor that takes const references to those types, unless they can be implicitly converted to `int`.